# Поочередное выполнение задач

Tags: java

Есть рабочий код на одну задачу деления в столбик. Нужно добавить еще одну задачу.

Это будет выглядеть как:

System.out.println(division.createLongDivision(1000, 15));
System.out.println(division.createLongDivision(1034, 15));

Но в выводе все перемешивается. Как реализовать правильную обработку двух и более задач?

```
public class Division {

    private StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder quotient = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder reminder = new StringBuilder();

    public String createLongDivision(int dividend, int divisor) {

        dividend = Math.abs(dividend);
        divisor = Math.abs(divisor);

        if (divisor == 0) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divisor can't be 0");

        }

        if (dividend < divisor) {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dividend can't be less than divisor");

        }

        String[] digits = String.valueOf(dividend).split("");
        Integer reminderNumber;
        Integer multiplyResult;
        Integer mod;

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {

            reminder.append(digits[i]);
            reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

            if (reminderNumber >= divisor) {

                mod = reminderNumber % divisor;
                multiplyResult = reminderNumber / divisor * divisor;

                String lastReminder = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", "_" + reminderNumber.toString());
                result.append(lastReminder).append("\n");

                String multiply = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "d", multiplyResult);
                result.append(multiply).append("\n");

                Integer tab = lastReminder.length() - calculateDigit(multiplyResult);
                result.append(createDivisor(multiplyResult, tab)).append("\n");

                quotient.append(reminderNumber / divisor);

                reminder.replace(0, reminder.length(), mod.toString());
                reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

            } 


            if (i == digits.length - 1) {

                result.append(String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", reminderNumber.toString())).append("\n");

            }
        }

        modifyResultView(dividend, divisor);
        return result.toString();

    }

    private String createDivisor (Integer multiplyResult, Integer tab) {

        return assemblyString(tab, ' ') + assemblyString(calculateDigit(multiplyResult), '-');

    }

    private int calculateDigit(int i) {

        return (int) Math.log10(i) + 1;

    }

    private String assemblyString(int numberOfSymbols, char symbol) {

        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSymbols; i++) {

            string.append(symbol);

        }

        return string.toString();

    }

    private void modifyResultView(Integer dividend, Integer divisor) {

        int[] index = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

            if (result.charAt(i) == '\n') {

                index[j] = i;

                j++;

            }

            if (j == 3) {

                break;

            }

        }

        int tab = calculateDigit(dividend) + 1 - index[0];
        result.insert(index[2], assemblyString(tab, ' ') + "│" + quotient.toString());
        result.insert(index[1], assemblyString(tab, ' ') + "│" + assemblyString(quotient.length(), '-'));
        result.insert(index[0], "│" + divisor);
        result.replace(1, index[0], dividend.toString());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Division division = new Division();

        System.out.println(division.createLongDivision(1000, 15));

        }

}
```

Comment: В каком смысле всё перемешивается? У вас однопоточное приложение. Тут не может ничего мешаться.

Comment: В прямом. Вывод ломается. Попробуйте запустить.

Comment: А чего вы хотели? Поля `result`, `quotient`, `reminder` вы обнуляете перед каждым расчётом? Нет. Их нужно либо очищать, либо для каждого расчёта создавать новый объект класса Division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте каждый раз новый объект `Division`

```
    System.out.println(new Division().createLongDivision(1000, 15));
    System.out.println(new Division().createLongDivision(1034, 15));
```

или реализуйте возврат состояния всех переменных объекта к исходным значениям после работы